# Update textbox value from another cpp

Tags: c++, class, winapi

I gotta fetch textbox value from another cpp file.
let's say
one.cpp is having the following code snippet which exactly creates the textbox.

```
CreateWindow(TEXT("Edit"), TEXT("test"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER, 100, 20, 140, 20, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

I wanna get the output or textbox value which we created above in one.cpp but from another cpp file namely second.cpp.

How would i do that?

Comment: What have you already tried? What was the result/problem?

Comment: Thanks for quick response.
what exactly the problem is
i can change textbox value dynamically in the same cpp file.

But, when it comes to access or interact with textbox from another cpp file is something what i want.

Could you understand what i'm saying?

Comment: What do you mean "another cpp file"? cpp files don't create text boxes, applications do. Do you mean from a different application? You know one application can be built from multiple cpp files, presumably? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Example1.Cpp

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
CreateWindow(TEXT("Edit"), TEXT("test"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER, 100, 20, 140, 20, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}

Example2.cpp

Form1->textBox1->Text = "Some Content" (This code can be valid in windows form application)

But, i'm developing Win32 app. since the above code is not valid, how can i change the textbox value from the example2.cpp

Ultimately, I hope you understand i'm trying to say

Comment: If I understood you correct, you could use [`GetDlgItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645481%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You need ID of the control and handle to the window. Is that what you have meant? If this doesn't help, please edit your question with **smallest** code snippet that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First, you must do two things to make that edit control usable. (1) Pass a unique ID as the HMENU parameter of the CreateWindow call. Control IDs are normally constants declared in resource.h. You will need to use that ID to detect messages from the edit control. (2) Save the HWND returned by CreateWindow in a global variable (HWND hwndEdit).

Now one.cpp can set or read the text using hwndEdit. Put the following declaration in one.h

```
extern HWND hwndEdit;
```

Add #include "one.h" in both cpp files. Now second.cpp can set or read the text using hwndEdit, exactly the same as in one.cpp.